# What does the expression "faire les poignes sur qqn/faire la poigne sur qqn" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions

Can someone please explain to me what this expression **faire les poignes sur qqn/faire la poigne sur qqn** mean?

I know that **avoir de la poigne** means to have enough energy for you to be obeyed, but I'm not sure the meaning is the same in the case of **faire la poigne sur**, or is it?

Comment: Dans cette expression je ne pense pas qu'il faille comprendre « poigne » au sens de force (comme dans l'expression *avoir de la poigne*) mais je prendrai poigne dans sons sens vieilli de « main ». Par cette expression Céline veut dire qu'il se fait la main sur (au sens figuré),  qu'il attaque (il est clair dans la phrase que ce sont des attaques verbales) la personne sur laquelle il veut se faire les poignes. Se faire la main/utiliser ses poings.

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette expression je ne pense pas qu'il faille comprendre « poigne » au sens de force (comme dans l'expression avoir de la poigne) mais je prendrai poigne dans sons sens vieilli de « main ».

Par cette expression Céline veut dire qu'il se fait la main sur (au sens figuré), qu'il attaque (il est clair dans la phrase que ce sont des attaques verbales) la personne sur laquelle il veut se faire les poignes. Se faire la main/utiliser ses poings.

Comment: Ça m'a aussi fait penser à _cogner, frapper, taper sur_. Je pense que j'ai plus souvent employé _avoir de la poigne_ pour des sens concrets, avec _pogne_en fait, avoir de la pogne pour _être capable d'agripper_, avoir un appui, avec l'idée de pouvoir tirer par la suite ou de se hisser dessus quelque chose. Je trouve cette expression de Céline sémantiquement astucieuse mais bien violente. Son propos dans cette œuvre est, évidemment, condamnable.